# Union recursive queries in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I need to union two different recursive queries. Somethink like:

```
with cte1 as
( select....
....
....
)
select * from cte1

union all

with cte2 as
( select....
....
....
)
select * from cte2
```

How can I do it? I received error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Do you know any workaroud it? I tried to search over internet but I can't find it..

Answer (score 9):

The order should be:

```
;WITH Cte1 AS
(
....
),
Cte2 AS
(
....
)
SELECT * FROM Cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Cte2
```

All your `CTE`s need to be at the beginning of the statement in a series.